# Setting hook state inside React useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm trying to create a custom data fetching hook for a React assignment from one of my courses. Is's a simple hook accessing a couple of REST API endpoints and creating an inventory object which the app uses for a sallad composing component. The problem is that I can't seem to set the internal state of the hook from within the `useEffect` hook which fetches the data. I've used this approach many times before, and I have literally no idea what causes this behaviour. Wherever i try to use `setContent` inside my `useEffect` function, it always remains `null`.

Please help!

```js
const useInventory = (baseURL) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [content, setContent] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);

        const types = ['foundations', 'extras', 'proteins', 'dressings'];
        const urls = types.map(endp => `${baseURL}/${endp}`);

        Promise
            .all(urls.map(u => fetch(u)))
            .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json())))
            .then(data => {

                const inventory = data.reduce((acc, curr, i) => 
                    ({ ...acc, [types[i]]: curr }),
                {});

                // This logs the inventory in desired format
                // e.g { foundations: Array, extras: Array, ... }
                console.log(inventory);
                setContent(inventory);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setError(err);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);

                // This logs null, for some reason
                console.log(content);
            });

    }, [baseURL]);

    return [content, loading, error];
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `setContent(null);`, also try making a sandbox (codesandbox.io)

Comment: Agreed. But as I just verified, this doesn't solve my problem. I will remove it from the post to avoid confusion. I'm running the API locally, but I'll try to get a sandbox up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting state is not synchronous you won't get updated content in finally block.

If you want to debug value of content changes you can use useEffect and console there like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(content); 
}, [content])
```

Comment: That is a great point, thank you so much! This does log a changed value for content, and now I notice some obvious mistakes which I've made in the parent component which uses the value.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will be pass

```js
const useInventory = baseURL => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [content, setContent] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    const types = ["foundations", "extras", "proteins", "dressings"];
    const urls = types.map(endp => `${baseURL}/${endp}`);
    function getData() {
      Promise.all(urls.map(u => fetch(u)))
        .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json())))
        .then(data => {
          const inventory = data.reduce(
            (acc, curr, i) => ({ ...acc, [types[i]]: curr }),
            {}
          );

          // This logs the inventory in desired format
          // e.g { foundations: Array, extras: Array, ... }
          console.log(inventory);
          setContent(inventory);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          setError(err);
        });
    }

    getData();
  }, [baseURL, content]);

  console.log(content);
  return [content, loading, error];
};
`
```